# Identity not redirecting to return url after login

Tags: asp.net-core

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, The code executes but does not redirect to the return URL. Is there anything you can spot that is wrong with my code? I've done this a thousand times before but for some reason I'm struggling today.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IdentityUser user =
            await userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Name);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                if((await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginModel.Password, false, false)).Succeeded)
                {
                    return Redirect(loginModel?.ReturnUrl ?? "/Admin/Index");
                }
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid name or password");
        return View(loginModel);
    }
```

The part that is apparently not working is `return Redirect(loginModel?.ReturnUrl ?? "/Admin/Index");`

Any suggestions you may have will be massively appreciated. Virtual drinks for all who help me solve my (hopefully) simple issue.

Comment: You need to check if `loginModel.ReturnUrl` is a non-null empty-string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out I was being silly.

When i called app.UseIdentity in the configure method of my startup i had a typo present, so it wasn't calling anything.

Thank you to @Tech Yogesh and @Dai for taking the time to help me in my time of need.

Answer (score 1):

As this is not any action but a relative url

Try

```
return LocalRedirect(loginModel?.ReturnUrl ?? "/Admin/Index");
```

Instead

```
return Redirect(loginModel?.ReturnUrl ?? "/Admin/Index");
```

**Update**

Try changing your code with this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
{
      if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
          return LocalRedirect(model.ReturnUrl);
}
else
{
     return LocalRedirect("/Admin/Index");
}
```

Comment: tThank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didnt work. I still end up at this url /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin

Comment: still the same result unfortunately